# Why chaining .andSelf() does not work?

Tags: jquery

Here is jsfiddle that exalains the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/4CuqR/

copy-pasted same fiddle code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p,div { margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 20px; }
  </style>  
</head>
<html>
<body>
  <DIV class="main">
    <span>Main Class</span>
    <DIV class="sub1">
      <span>sub1 Class</span>
      <p>Hello P1</p>
      <p>Hello P2</p>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $('.main').children('.sub1').children('p:first').andSelf().andSelf().css("color", "red");
  });​
  </script>
</html>
```

In above code, ideally **DIV.main** should also be red.

Here is the **output of above code**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me explain a bit...

Your code below

```
$('.main').children('.sub1').children('p:first')
```

gives you the element

```
<p>Hello P1</p>
```

Now, when you add the first `.andSelf()`, it gives you the elements

```
<DIV class="sub1">
  <span>sub1 Class</span>
  <p>Hello P1</p>
  <p>Hello P2</p>
</DIV>
```

Next, when you add the second `.andSelf()`, it still gives you the same elements

```
<DIV class="sub1">
  <span>sub1 Class</span>
  <p>Hello P1</p>
  <p>Hello P2</p>
</DIV>
```

So, your code doesn't works and the **DIV.main** is not red.

So, just try this:

```
$('.main').children('.sub1').andSelf().children('p:first').andSelf().css("color","red");
```

This will select the **DIV.main** also and add the css.

Here the code below

```
$('.main').children('.sub1').andSelf()
```

Gives us the below elements

```
<DIV class="main">
   <span>Main Class</span>
   <DIV class="sub1">
      <span>sub1 Class</span>
      <p>Hello P1</p>
      <p>Hello P2</p>
   </DIV>
</DIV>​
```

Next, when you add the second `.andSelf()`, it still gives you the same elements

```
<DIV class="main">
   <span>Main Class</span>
   <DIV class="sub1">
      <span>sub1 Class</span>
      <p>Hello P1</p>
      <p>Hello P2</p>
   </DIV>
</DIV>​
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your `.andSelf()`s around:

```
$('.main').children('.sub1').andSelf().children('p:first').andSelf().css("color","red");​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4CuqR/2/**.

This is a pretty convoluted selector.

- The first `.andSelf()` selects:

  ```
    $('.main').children('.sub1')
  + $('.main')
  ```
- The second `.andSelf()` then adds in:

  ```
    $('.main').children('.sub1').andSelf().children('p:first')
  + $('.main').children('.sub1')
  + $('.main')
  ```